# Como criar um port scanner UDP em python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Meu código sempre está dando "port is opened". A minha ideia é: se o destino responder, a porta está aberta. Caso contrário, pode estar filtrada...

```
#####################################
# Portscan UDP        #
# #
#####################################
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket

ip = (input("Type IP or Address: "))

ports = []
count = 0

while count < 5:
    ports.append(int(input("Type the port: ")))
    count += 1


for port in ports:
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    client.bind((ip, port))
    msg = 'hi'
    client.sendto(msg.encode(), (ip,port))
    data, address = client.recvfrom(1024)
    #print("Recebida ->", str(data))




    if data != None:
         print (str(port) + " -> Port is opened")
    else:
         print (str(port) + " -> Port is closed")

print ("Scan Finished")
```

Comment: Mas qual é mesmo o problema? corri o codigo e parece estar tudo bem, uma exceção é lançada quando a porta está em uso

Comment: Sempre dá que todas as portas estão abertas. Aparentemente não funciona!

Comment: Nop, ora tente lá colocar a 80. No meu gera logo uma excepção. Mais precisamente: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Comment: Tem que rodar como root!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se este resulta:

```
import socket

ip = '127.0.0.1'
while True:
    port = input('port?\n')
    if(port == 'exit'): break
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect((ip, int(port)))
        print('Port {} open'.format(port))
    except:
        print('Port {} not open'.format(port))
    s.close()
```

Comment: Vou testar. Obrigado, @Miguel

Comment: Pode verificar com nmap: sudo nmap -sS -O -p 80 127.0.0.1 ... "-p..." é a porta que quer verificar, neste caso é a 80

Comment: obrigado! Funcionou

Comment: hehe ainda bem @PaulSigonoso, vi que perguntou também no SOen mas sem resposta ainda. Se obter alguma resposta lá diga-me aqui com o link respetivo, pois estou curioso acerca de outras maneiras de fazer

Comment: Pode deixar! Obrigado. Estou aprendendo bastante aqui!

Comment: Olhe vou editar @PaulSigonoso, reparei num erro... se testar a porta 80 por mais do que uma vez ela começa a dar como "not open". Mas já corrigi e vou colocar

Comment: Eu também fiz uma outra pergunta: Como criar um port scanner TCP usando o método SYN (TCP SYN)? O único que eu fiz "mais ou menos" foi o TCP scan "normal".

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44165/discussion-between-miguel-and-paul-sigonoso).